# Pyenv activate does not run activate script with Fish Shell

Tags: virtualenv, fish, pyenv

My pyenv is working just fine, but it does not seem to be running my activate script located at `/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/project/bin/activate.fish`

When activating my environment it gives the following output, but it does not echo anything from the activate script, which indicates that it is not running.

```
dani@localhost ~/d/project> pyenv activate project
pyenv-virtualenv: prompt changing not working for fish.
```

Of course I can just `source` the file manually, but I'm too eager to find out why it is not running. Is there some kind of debug mode? I'm not sure how to approach.

Answer (score 5):

Actually,

Virtual environment is activated but the message just says that your prompt wasn't changed. Updating prompt was intentionally removed from fish shell.
you can find detailed information here;
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/153

If you want to see virtual environment is really activated or not,
run the following command;

`pyenv which python`

it should print something like;
`.pyenv/versions/{your-virtual-env}/bin/python`

Comment: I'm sorry for causing misunderstanding about the activation of the virtual environment: that part is working correct. It's the activate script which is causing the trouble: it should run when I activate my environment, but it does not and I'm eager to find out why. Any thoughts on that part perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
set PYENV_ROOT $HOME/.pyenv
set -x PATH $PYENV_ROOT/shims $PYENV_ROOT/bin $PATH
pyenv rehash
```

Comment: describe your answer some more

Comment: I installed Pyenv through homebrew so my PYENV_ROOT is a different one and so are the shims and bin folder relative to the PYENV_ROOT. But all of these are included in my PATH, but that won't lead to my activate scripts corresponding to the environment I activate, being triggered.